# Read a text file with tab and semicolon in R

Tags: r, import, read.table

I'm trying to import a text file containing informations as follows:

```
Date (Tab) ON/OFF (Tab) 93489;123985;219389;1324;2349
Date (Tab) ON/OFF (Tab) 34536;34566;12346;235346;32567
Date (Tab) ON/OFF (Tab) 6346;235;6547457;2345;4576782
```

So I use the `read.table()` or `read.csv()` with the argument `sep=";"` or `sep="\t"`.
They work, but not both together. Is there a better way to import these data? Read a file that uses both tabs and semicolon?

Finally, I need the extracted values, but at the moment, that is not possible, because I get something like this (including the " )

```
"18315;18316;18317;18318;18319;18320;18708"
"20317;20318;20319;20320;20321;20322;20714"
```

I can replace the ";" with " ", but it is still a string and `strsplit()` won't work...

```
"85626"
"81657 83249"
"84165 84560 84561 84957 85351 85746 85747 85748 86143"
"77701 78097 78893 86148 86149 86150"
```

Comment: Use `sep = "\t"` first and split the data once it's in R. there are several posts here that should show how to split a concatenated column up after reading it into R.

Comment: @Anando Mahto: finally it worked with `read.csv` and `\t` as separator and then strsplit worked using `as.matrix(strsplit(as.character(newdata2), split = ";"))` after deleting the non-necessary columns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not first replace the tab (or multi-space) with a semi-colon then import as normal:

```
tx<-"Date  ON/OFF  93489;123985;219389;1324;2349
Date  ON/OFF  34536;34566;12346;235346;32567
Date  ON/OFF  6346;235;6547457;2345;4576782"

read.table(text=gsub("([ /t]){2,9}",";",tx),header=F,sep=";")

    V1     V2    V3     V4      V5     V6      V7
1 Date ON/OFF 93489 123985  219389   1324    2349
2 Date ON/OFF 34536  34566   12346 235346   32567
3 Date ON/OFF  6346    235 6547457   2345 4576782
```

Here's a 2 step version to deal with the number of ;-separated items being irregular:

```
df<-read.table(text=tx,header=F,stringsAsFactors=F)    # read table with ;-sep chars as one col

x.list<-strsplit(df[,ncol(df)],";")                    # turn the last row into a list, split by ;
max.length<-max(sapply(x.list,length))                 # work out the max length

cbind(df[,1:ncol(df)-1],                               # bind the first columns
  t(                                                   # to the transposed matrix
    sapply(x.list,function(x){length(x)<-max.length    # of the list, with each element expanded
                              x})                      # to max.length items (NAs for missing)
  )
)

    V1     V2     1      2       3      4       5     6
1 Date ON/OFF 93489 123985  219389   1324    2349  <NA>
2 Date ON/OFF 34536  34566   12346 235346   32567  <NA>
3 Date ON/OFF  6346    235 6547457   2345 4576782 43455
```

Comment: Nice solution. Could you explain the {2,9} please.

Comment: just to cater for multi-space, when i copied and pasted it it turned the tab into 2 spaces, so this matched 2-9 spaces.

Comment: @user3319871 it's a bit more complicated that way - you need to split out the ;-separated column and make it regular - see above

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we have the test data:

```
Lines <- "Date\tON/OFF\t93489;123985;219389;1324;2349
Date\tON/OFF\t34536;34566;12346;235346;32567
Date\tON/OFF\t6346;235;6547457;2345;4576782
"
```

We will use this for the purpose of reproducibility but in reality you would use something like the commented out lines:

**1) read.table** Read the data with a tab separator and then re-read the third column using a semicolon separator.  Finally combine them:

```
# d1 <- read.table("myfile", as.is = TRUE)
d1 <- read.table(text = Lines, as.is = TRUE)
d2 <- read.table(text = d1[[3]], sep = ";")
d <- cbind(d1[1:2], d2)
```

giving:

```
    V1     V2    V1     V2      V3     V4      V5
1 Date ON/OFF 93489 123985  219389   1324    2349
2 Date ON/OFF 34536  34566   12346 235346   32567
3 Date ON/OFF  6346    235 6547457   2345 4576782
```

**2) read.pattern** There is a new function `read.pattern` in the development version of the [gsubfn](http://gsubfn.googlecode.com) package that makes this simple to do:

```
library(gsubfn)
source("http://gsubfn.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/R/read.pattern.R")

# read.pattern("myfile", pattern = "[^[:space:];]+")
read.pattern(text = Lines, pattern = "[^[:space:];]+")
```

giving:

```
    V1 V2  V3    V4     V5      V6     V7      V8
1 Date ON OFF 93489 123985  219389   1324    2349
2 Date ON OFF 34536  34566   12346 235346   32567
3 Date ON OFF  6346    235 6547457   2345 4576782
```

*REVISED* In second solution changed regular expression in pattern argument and changed `https` to `http` in `source` statement.

Comment: thanks, didn't work according to my faults I think, but I got it to do what I want... ;)

Comment: ok, thanks. Well, I'm new to R and more a beginner in programming, so...
but as I mentioned above, I got the result I needed using `as.matrix(strsplit(as.character(newdata2), split = ";"))` after deleting the non-necessary columns

Comment: I have made some changes to the second solution which should allow it to handle a greater range of inputs.